Finding the asymptotic rate of growth of a table of values
Suppose we define entropy[k] where:
Clear["*Global`*"]
F[r_] := F[r] = 
  DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[Range[0, t]/t, {t, 1, r}]]]
S1[k_] := 
 S1[k] = Sort[Select[F[k], Boole[IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2]] == 1 &]]
S2[k_] := 
 S2[k] = Sort[Select[F[k], Boole[IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2]] == 0 &]]
P1[k_] := P1[k] = Join[Differences[S1[k]], Differences[S2[k]]]
U1[k_] := U1[k] = P1[k]/Total[P1[k]]
entropy[k_] := entropy[k] = N[Total[-U1[k] Log[2, U1[k]]]]

Question: How do we determine the rate of growth of T=Table[{k,entropy[k]},{k,1,Infinity}] using mathematica?
Attempt:
We can't actually take infinite values from T, but we could replace Infinity with a large integer.
If we define
T=Join[Table[{k, entropy[k]}, {k, 3, 30}], Table[{10 k, entropy[10 k]}, {k, 3, 10}]]

We could visualize the points using ListPlot

It seems the following function should fit:
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[
  T, {a + b Log2[x], {a, b}, x]

We end up with:
nlm1=2.72984 Log[E,x]-1.49864

However, when we add additional points to T
 T=Join[Table[{k, entropy[k]}, {k, 3, 30}], Table[{10 k, entropy[10 k]}, {k, 3, 10}],
       Table[{100 k, entropy[100 k]}, {k, 1, 10}]]

We end up with:
nlm1=2.79671 Log[E,x]-1.6831

 My guess is we can bound T with the function $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{3\ln(x)-2}$; however, I could only go up to {3000,entropy[3000]} and need more accurate bounds. 
Edit: I need approximation by asymptotic expansion, not an upper bound?
Is there an asymptotic expansion we can use?

Small comment: Because you sort by numeric values, I think the removal of duplicates is not strictly needed. Their presence will just give some extra zeros in the two lists from which P1 is formed.

Also: How/why did Log[2,x] become Log[x,E]? I realize they are related. But what motivates that change?

@DanielLichtblau The output of nlm1 return Log[x,E] instead of Log[x,2]; however, I don't know why? Perhaps, if I write nlm[x] the output will go back to Log[x,2].

Ah. Maybe use Log2 instead of Log? Also I think you are reversing x and E.

It still returns Log instead of Log2. (I'll reverse x and E.)

I believe one can get a cheap asymptotic upper bound of 2*Log[2,k]+1. I suspect one might be able to improve on the constant term but do not know how to do that.

I am still having a hard time finding an approximation, but for the more basic case where F[r_]:= F[r] = Range[0, r]/r
We can show that for even k,
entropyEVEN[k_] := -((2^-IntegerExponent[k, 2] k Log[4] +    k Log[2^(-2 + IntegerExponent[k, 2])] - 2 (-1 + k) Log[-1 + k])/(  2 (-1 + k) Log[2]))
I am trying to find a way to extend this to when F[r_] := F[r] =    DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[Range[0, t]/t, {t, r-1, r}]]] , F[r_]:= ..., {t, r-2, r}]]], ... , F[r_]:= ..., {t, 1, r}]]] but it's quite difficult right now

It may be helpful to consider cases where $k$ is a power of 2, and start with F[r_]:= F[r] = Range[0, r]/r and work downward with the next range table included Range[0,r-1]/r-1 etc.

Three remarks on upper bound of entropy[k]. (1) U1[k] is a partition of the interval [0,1]. Therefore, entropy[k] bounded from above by the value Log[2,Length[U1[k]]], which is realized by dividing [0,1] evenly. (2) Using some knowledge of number theory, one can show that U1[k] is equal to Sum[EulerPhi[j],{j,2,k}]. This is also commented in OEIS. (3) Sum[EulerPhi[j],{j,1,k}] is known as Totient Summatory Function, and its asymptotic series is known.

Conclusion
An approximation that appears to either approach constant or at least sub-logarithmic error for sufficiently large $k$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{entropy}(n) & \approx -f(k) \log _2\left(\frac{f(k)}{2}\right) \sum _i^{\frac{k}{2}} \phi (2 i-1) + C\\
\mathrm{with}\\\\
f(k) & = \frac{\pi ^2 k}{2(k-3) (k-1)^2} \\
C & \approx \log _2\left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Where $\phi(i)$ is  Euler's totient function. The value of $C$ is just an observational guess, I really wouldn't put a lot of confidence in its exact value.
This arises from finding the average values of the Differences of S1 and S2 as a function of k, and observing that Length@F[k] == 1 + Sum[EulerPhi[i], {i, k}]

We can also use the asymptotic growth of $\sum_i^k \phi(i)$ to further simplify:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_i^{k/2} \phi(i) & \approx 3 \frac{k^2}{4\pi^2} - 1\\
\frac{\sum _i^{\frac{k}{2}} \phi (2 i-1)}{\sum _i^{\frac{k}{2}} \phi (i)} & \approx \frac{8}{3} \\
\sum _i^{\frac{k}{2}} \phi (2 i-1) & \approx \frac{2 k^2}{\pi ^2}-\frac{8}{3}
\end{align}
$$
to get a simpler approximation:
$$
\mathrm{entropy}(k) \approx -\left(\frac{2 k^2}{\pi ^2}-\frac{8}{3}\right) f(k) \log _2\left(\frac{f(k)}{2}\right)+C
$$

And using $f \approx \frac{\pi ^2}{2 k^2}$ (See @Arbuja 's comment below):
$$
\mathrm{entropy}(k) \approx \left(-1 + \frac{4 \pi ^2}{3 k^2}\right) \log _2\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{4 k^2}\right) + C
$$
Which can be further simplified to see the asymptotic limit:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{entropy}(k) &\approx \left(-1 + \frac{4 \pi ^2}{3 k^2}\right) \log _2\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{4 k^2}\right) + C \\\\
\mathrm{entropy}(k) &\approx \left(\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3 k^2}-1\right) \log _2\left(\left(\frac{\pi }{2 k}\right)^2\right) +C\\\\
\mathrm{entropy}(k) &\approx 2 \left(\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3 k^2}-1\right) \left(-\log _2(k)-1+\log _2(\pi )\right)+C \\\\
\mathrm{entropy}(k) &\approx 2 \log _2(k) + \frac{8 \pi ^2}{3 k^2} \left(-\log _2(k)-1+\log _2(\pi )\right) + C+2-2 \log _2(\pi )\\\\
\mathrm{entropy}(k) &\approx 2 \log _2(k) + K \\\\
K &= C+2-2 \log _2(\pi ) = 1 - \log_2(3\pi)
\end{align}
$$

Here we see the comparison plot of the approximation and the true entropy (and using @azerbajdzan 's newentropy for faster comparison with $RecursionLimit = 5000:
f[k_] := (k \[Pi]^2)/(2 (k - 3) (k - 1)^2)
entropyApprox[
  k_] := -f[k] (Log[2, f[k]/2]) Sum[EulerPhi[2 i - 1], {i, k/2}] + 
  Log2[Pi/6]
entropyVeryApprox[
   k_] := -f[k] (Log[2, f[k]/2]) (-(8/3) + (2 k^2)/\[Pi]^2) + 
   Log2[Pi/6];

testValuesK = Join[Range[2000], Range[3000, 5000, 500]];

plot = DiscretePlot[{newentropy[k], entropyApprox[k]}, {k, 
   testValuesK}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"k", "entropy(k)"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], Filling -> None, 
  Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"entropy(k)", "entropyApprox(k)"}]



And we see the error is either approaching 0, or is growing extremely slowly (note the $k$ step size is changed from 1 to 500 past $k = 2000$, due to how long newentropy takes to calculate for large k) :
errsAtK = ({#, newentropy[#] - entropyApprox[#]}) & /@ testValuesK;
ListLinePlot[errsAtK, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"k", "error"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium]]


Zooming in on the error just for $k ≥ 1000$, we see the error appears to be settling around 0 (notice it goes up and then back down towards the end):

So although $C$ might not be exactly correct, the error does appear to be staying somewhat constant and not growing.
Also note the approximation using the limit of the sum of $\phi(i)$ tends towards the other approximation:
DiscretePlot[{entropyApprox[k] - entropyVeryApprox[k]}, {k, 5000}]




Walkthrough
Note: all Analysis is for even $k ≥ 4$, this made things easier. This is fine since if you zoom out enough on entropy[k] it appears smooth.
Means of the differences of S1[k],S2[k]
Notice that the minimum value of Differences@S2[k] is
$$
\frac{1}{4 \left(\frac{k}{2}-1\right)^2-1}
$$
min[k_] := 1/(4*(k/2 - 1)^2 - 1)
And @@ Table[Min@Differences@Sort@S2[k] == min[k], {k, 4, 100, 2}]
(*True*)

Next notice that the mean of the differences of S2[k] divided by min[k] approaches a constant, and it appears to be exactly $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$:
Table[Mean@Differences@Sort@S2[2^k]/(min[2^k]*Pi^2/2), {k, 2, 12}] // 
 N

(*{0.202642, 0.545576, 0.806434, 0.855284, 0.943945, 0.966921,
0.988094, 0.990977, 0.996279, 0.997858, 0.999265}*)


So the mean of the differences of S2[k] for large k is
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{2} * \frac{1}{4 \left(\frac{k}{2}-1\right)^2-1}
$$
Also observe that for large $k$, the mean of $S1[k]$ is twice the mean of $S2[k]$:
Table[Mean@Differences@Sort@S1[2^k]/
  Mean@Differences@Sort@S2[2^k], {k, 2, 12}] // N

(*{0.75, 1.21875, 1.42917, 1.81534, 1.84152, 1.9333, 1.95468, 1.98692,
1.99061, 1.99604, 1.99716}*)

So the mean of the differences of S1[k] for large k is
$$
 \frac{\pi^2}{4 \left(\frac{k}{2}-1\right)^2-1}
$$
min[k_] := 1/(4*(k/2 - 1)^2 - 1)
meanDiffS1[k_] := Pi^2 * min[k]
meanDiffS2[k_] := meanDiffS1[k]/2

Lengths of S1[k], S2[k]
It can be shown that the length of S1[k] is
$$
\mathrm{length ~of~ S1[k]} = \sum _i^{\frac{k}{2}} \phi (2 i)
$$
While the length of S2[k] is the same sum but over the odds plus 1:
$$
\mathrm{length ~of~ S2[k]} = 1 + \sum _i^{\frac{k}{2}} \phi (2 i -1)
$$
Table[Length@S1[k] - Sum[EulerPhi[2 i], {i, k/2}], {k, 4, 100, 
   2}] // DeleteDuplicates
(*{0}*)

Table[Length@S2[k] - (1 + Sum[EulerPhi[2 i - 1], {i, k/2}]), {k, 4, 
  100, 2}]
(*{0}*)

And the Differences of S1 and S2 will just have this length minus 1:
lenDiffS1[k_] := Sum[EulerPhi[2 i], {i, k/2}] - 1
lenDiffS2[k_] := Sum[EulerPhi[2 i - 1], {i, k/2}]

Total of P1[k]
Now observe the Total of Diffferences@S1[k] is:
$$
\frac{k-2}{k}
$$
totS1[k_] := (k - 2)/k
Table[Total@Differences@S1[k] - totS1[k], {k, 4, 100, 
   2}] // DeleteDuplicates
(*{0}*)

While the total of S2[k] is always 1:
Table[Total@Differences@S2[k] - 1, {k, 4, 100, 2}] // DeleteDuplicates
(*{0}*)

meaning that the total of P1[k] is $ 1 + \frac{k-2}{k}$
totS1[k_] := (k - 2)/k
totP[k_] := 1 + totS1[k]
Table[Total@P1[k] - totP[k], {k, 4, 100, 2}] // DeleteDuplicates
(*{0}*)

Adding together entropy contributions of S1[k] and S2[k]
Since we know the mean of the differences of S1 and S2 and their respective lengths, and the total of P1, we can calculate mean contributions (very roughly, I would much prefer to find the mean of each elements entropy -U1[k]*Log2[U1[k] but I couldn't find a regular behavior to this) of S1 and S2 to the entropy:
contribS1[k_] := 
 lenDiffS1[k]*(-(meanDiffS1[k]/totP[k])*Log2[meanDiffS1[k]/totP[k]])

contribS2[k_] := 
 lenDiffS2[k]*(-(meanDiffS2[k]/totP[k])*Log2[meanDiffS2[k]/totP[k]])

totEntropy[k_] := contribS2[k] + contribS2[k]

And simplifying:
Simplify[totEntropy1[k], k \[Element] PositiveIntegers]

(*-1/2*(k*Pi^2*Log[(k*Pi^2)/(4*(-3 + k)*(-1 + k)^2)]*Sum[EulerPhi[-1 + 2*i], {i, k/2}])/((-3 + k)*(-1 + k)^2*Log[2])*)

gives us:
$$
\mathrm{entropy}(k) \approx -\frac{\pi ^2 k \log \left(\frac{\pi ^2 k}{4 (k-3) (k-1)^2}\right) \sum _i^{\frac{k}{2}} \phi (2 i-1)}{2 (k-3) (k-1)^2 \log (2)}
$$
Which appears to be off by a constant value that might be around $\log_2{\frac{\pi}{6}}$, although this is really just a guess
Ways to Improve
Describing the Distribution of $S_i[k]$
Note that using the means of the differences of S1 and S2 is kind of a sin, because in the end it gets transformed by -U1[k] *Log2[U1[k]. The distributions of S1[k] and S2[k] are also not tightly distributed about the mean:
frameLabels = {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(differences\), \(mean\)]\)", 
   "prob."};
s1Hist = 
 Histogram[Differences@S1[2^12]/meanDiffS1[2^12], "FreedmanDiaconis", 
  "Probability", Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> frameLabels, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium]]
s2Hist = 
 Histogram[Differences@S2[2^12]/meanDiffS2[2^12], "FreedmanDiaconis", 
  "Probability", Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> frameLabels, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium]]



The shape of the distributions of S1 and S2 appear identical, and for sufficiently large k the shape appears to approach whatever this distribution is. If someone can describe this distribution better than just using the mean, this could improve estimates on entropy[k]
Describing the mean of e[k] := -U1[k]* Log2[U1[k]]
An even better improvement would be for describing the mean of each individual entropy in the list -U1[k] * Log2[U1[k]]. This would exactly describe entropy[k] since it's just the sum of the individual entropies.
I originally hoped to do this, but I could find no regular pattern in how the mean of -U1[k] * Log[k] behaves:
e[k_] := e[k] = -U1[k]*Log2[U1[k]]

Table[Mean[e[2^k]]/(-min[2^k]*Log2[min[2^k]]), {k, 2, 13}] // N

(*{0.873814, 1.37538, 1.95718, 2.26098, 2.5353, 2.6853, 2.79824, \
2.8629, 2.91559, 2.9536, 2.98467, 3.00889}*)

I could guess that Mean[e[k] looks something like  -x * min[k]*Log2[x*min[k]] or -x * min[k]*Log2[min[k]] but the ratio isn't really slowing down enough for me to confidently say that Mean[e[k] is  related to the entropy of min[k] like this.
If someone can find an approximate relationship for the mean of the entropy:
$$
\mathrm{Mean(e(k))} \approx g(k)
$$
Then we can probably get a much better approximation since we know the length of e[k] to be
$$
\mathrm{Length~of~e(k)} = \sum _i^{k} \phi (i)-1
$$
so
$$
\mathrm{entropy}(k) \approx g(k) \sum _i^{k} \phi (i)-1
$$
And using the asymptotic limit of $\sum _i^{k} \phi (i)$:
$$
\mathrm{entropy}(k) \approx g(k) (3 \frac{k^2}{\pi^2} - 2)
$$
It may be helpful to note that e[k] also has a distribution which has a constant shape for large k, but I don't know how to describe this distribution either:
eHist = Histogram[e[2^12], "FreedmanDiaconis", "Probability", 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"individual entropy values", "prob."},
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium]]


Additional comment for further exploration
Notice that S1 and S2 can be defined recursively by finding the coprimes of k in Range[k]:
coprimes[k_] := Select[Range@k,  CoprimeQ[#, k] &]
newS1Elems[k_] := newS1Elems[k] = If[EvenQ[k], coprimes[k]/k, {}]
newS2Elems[k_] := newS2Elems[k] = If[OddQ[k], coprimes[k]/k, {}]

And then initialize and S1 and S2 and Join the new elements:
S1New[1] = {};
S1New[k_] := S1New[k] = Join[S1New[k - 1], newS1Elems[k]] // Sort

S2New[1] = {0, 1};
S2New[k_] := S2New[k] = Join[S2New[k - 1], newS2Elems[k]] // Sort

I don't think this will speed up calculating entropy, but I'm wondering if thinking about it this way will bring any new insights.

Would the simplest approximation for large $k$ be $-\left(1-\frac{4\pi^2}{3k^2}\right)\log_{2}(\frac{\pi^2}{4k^2})+C$?

Oh yes that works also because $f(k) \approx \frac{\pi ^2}{2 k^2}$

That does not seem to be a better approximation than what is in my answer. My errors (differences) are around 0.005 while yours are around 0.05 (ten times bigger). Yet, I used a simpler formula and you used complicated formula that provides less accurate result?

Very nice. You may have saved me the trouble of posting what I have. I'll show it, provided it differs in some substantial way once I reread yours.

@azerbajdzan while your fit looks good for $k \leq 300$, the error continues to grow if you plot it out past $k = 300$ comparison here (note that the weird smoothness after $k=2000$ is because I change the $k$ step size to 1000 because it would otherwise take too long to calculate newentropy at all of those high $k$ values)
$$ $$
If you fit your model with more $k$ values, it should approach the asymptotic limit shown above $2 \log _2(k)+1-\log _2(3 \pi )$
$$ $$
It might be worth trying to fit the model a*Log2[k] + b with m=1000 to confirm this.

@DanielLichtblau I would really like to see what you found!

@ydd Can yo see it is an computation error? I mean your third plot. Something happened at around 2000, data above that point are useless. Same with your image in the comment. Second issue is that I do not see how you compared the two approximations. My approximation error is around 0.005 not as is depicted in your image.

@azerbajdzan I changed the $k$ step size to 1000 after $k = 2000$ because newentropy takes a long time to calculate for large $k$ because Length@U1[k] grows like $k^2$. Below $k = 2000$ the $k$ step size is 1. That's why you see sudden change in the plot

@ydd You did not mention you changed step at 2000. But still the image in the comment is not correct. As I already mention several times, my approximation error is around 0.005 not 0.05.

@azerbajdzan I'll edit it to point it out. You need to plot your errors past $k=300$

@ydd Look at image in my answer. It is up to 1000 and still not more than 0.005. I am not sure what you plotted but simply it is wrong.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@ydd This is the correct comparison not the one you posted in the comment above. https://i.sstatic.net/pTyld1fg.png

@azerbajdzan But this fit is with more data points (i'm guessing up to $k=3000$). Your fit relies on having more and more data points to get a better fit, entropyApprox does not rely on that because it's an observation on the mean values of the differences of S1[k] and S2[k] and their lengths. It also at least provides some insight on why the function grows logarithmically in the limit, as I showed it should approach a similar function to your fit, I.e. $$ \mathrm{entropy}(k) \approx 2 \log_2(k) + 1 - \log_2(3 \pi)$$ ... cont'd

with a  $\left(\frac{8 \pi^2 }{3 k^2} \right) \left(-\log_2(k) - 1 + \log_2(\pi) \right)$ term that vanishes.

@azerbajdzan Also the issue with the first plot was I didn't see your fit up to $k=1000$ and used the one only up to $k = 300$, If you look in the continued chat I compared using your fit up to $k = 1000$

@ydd Your approximation computed for range 5000 still oscillates beyond my fit computed only on data up to 1000. Yes, the fit needs more data to be more precise, but it is the same as your approximation - it needs summation of Euler Phi (i.e. it needs more data to be more precise the same way). Only advantage is that it is faster to compute summation on Euler Phi than computation needed for my fit.

This is just an extended comment.
It might be that the rate of growth for large values of $k$ is not linear in the log of $k$.
First, generate some entropy values a bit more uniform in the range from 3 to 3,0000, fit the log/linear function, and plot the results with a log/linear plot:
T = Join[Table[{k, entropy[k]}, {k, Join[Range[3, 10], Range[20, 100, 10],
  Range[200, 1000, 100], Range[2000, 4000, 1000]]}]];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[T, a + b  Log[k], {a, b}, k];
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[T, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"k", "Entropy"}],
 LogLinearPlot[nlm[k], {k, 3, 4000}]]


But looking at the residuals vs k suggests that a linear-in-the-logs function does not fit the complete range of values of $k$:
ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{T[[All, 1]], nlm["FitResiduals"]}],
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"k", "Residual"}]


We see that the fit for large values of $k$ (the values the OP states are more important), the fit is not good.  Suppose we now just look at values of $k \geq 500$:
T2 = Select[T, #[[1]] >= 500 &];
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[T2, a + b  Log[k], {a, b}, k];
ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{T2[[All, 1]], nlm2["FitResiduals"]}]]


We see a similar pattern of residuals which suggests (to me) that either a linear rate of change of entropy in the log of $k$ is inadequate or that such a summary of the rate of change does not occur until the value of $k$ is larger than $k=3,000$.

I use a variant of the definitions which is slightly faster I think.
ff2[n_] := 
 ff2[n] = Flatten[Join[{0, 1}, Table[Range[1, j - 1]/j, {j, n}]]]
ss1[k_] := 
 ss1[k] = Sort[N@Select[ff2[k], IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2] &]]
ss2[k_] := 
 ss2[k] = Sort[N@Select[ff2[k], ! IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2] &]]
pp1[k_] := pp1[k] = Join[Differences[ss1[k]], Differences[ss2[k]]]
uu1[k_] := uu1[k] = pp1[k]/Total[pp1[k]] /. 0. -> Nothing
entropy2[k_] := entropy2[k] = N[Total[-uu1[k]  Log[2, uu1[k]]]]

Here are a couple of runs using fairly large inputs.
Timing[entropytable = 
  Table[PrintTemporary[n]; entropy2[n], {n, 200, 5000, 200}]]

(* Out[23]= {179.603, {13.1198, 15.1009, 16.2643, 17.0921, 17.7338, 
  18.2577, 18.702, 19.0862, 19.4254, 19.7295, 20.0035, 20.2543, 
  20.4851, 20.6985, 20.8974, 21.0834, 21.2582, 21.4229, 21.5789, 
  21.7267, 21.8672, 22.0015, 22.1295, 22.2523, 22.37}} *)

Timing[entropytablebig = 
  Table[PrintTemporary[n]; entropy2[n], {n, 6000, 10000, 2000}]]

(* Out[24]= {162.95, {22.8956, 23.7254, 24.3689}} *)

So how to assess asymptotics?
First thing, noted by @ydd, is that we want to know how many values we're using for a given input n. This is estimated to first approximation as 3/Pi^2*n^2. Computations below show this to be a sound estimate.
It is straightforward to then find the average value of the differences. What we want is actually an average of differences times log of differences. I do not know how to find that. First leap of faith: I instead use average of differences times average of logs. I do not know how to bound the error of discrepancy, but I'm fairly certain it is small. So this step is a leap of faith.
Next is to realize we do not know the average of the logs of differences. We of course know the log of the average diff (since we know the af=verage diff). A bit of thought shows that these differ by the log of (ratio of the geometric to arithmetic mean of the diffs). Computations below indicate that this seems stable.
top = 3000;
fracs = Select[pp1[top], # > 10^(-14) &] // Sort;
{Length[fracs], With[{m = top}, Round[3./Pi^2*m^2]]}
mn = Mean[fracs];
gmn = GeometricMean[fracs];
agquot = mn/gmn

(* Out[89]= {2736187, 2735672}

Out[92]= 1.32189 *)

top = 5000;
fracs = Select[pp1[top], # > 10^(-14) &] // Sort;
{Length[fracs], With[{m = top}, Round[3./Pi^2*m^2]]}
mn = Mean[fracs];
gmn = GeometricMean[fracs];
agquot = mn/gmn

(* Out[95]= {7600457, 7599089}

Out[98]= 1.32211 *)

I also show this for odd values, to indicate that it does not change between evens and odds.
top = 4001;
fracs = Select[pp1[top], # > 10^(-14) &] // Sort;
{Length[fracs], With[{m = top}, Round[3./Pi^2*m^2]]}
mn = Mean[fracs];
gmn = GeometricMean[fracs];
agquot = mn/gmn

(* Out[101]= {4867601, 4865849}

Out[104]= 1.32211 *)

top = 6001;
fracs = Select[pp1[top], # > 10^(-14) &] // Sort;
{Length[fracs], With[{m = top}, Round[3./Pi^2*m^2]]}
mn = Mean[fracs];
gmn = GeometricMean[fracs];
agquot = mn/gmn

(* Out[107]= {10948795, 10946336}

Out[110]= 1.32228 *)

Now a higher value, to show it seems not to grow.
top = 10000;
fracs = Select[pp1[top], # > 10^(-13) &] // Sort;
{Length[fracs], With[{m = top}, Round[3./Pi^2*m^2]]}
mn = Mean[fracs];
gmn = GeometricMean[fracs];
agquot = mn/gmn

(* Out[113]= {30397485, 30396355}

Out[116]= 1.32222 *)

What this indicates is, subject to the leap of faith noted above, our entropy estimate is like so:
estimated[n_] := (2*Log[2, N@n] + 1 - Log[2, 2/3.*Pi^2]) - Log[2, 1.3222]

Here I have used some facts already noted by others, that the sum of the diffs asymptotically approaches 2 (it is 2-2/n, to be specific), so the log average has a denominator of 2, hence a term -Log[1/2] or +1. The rest comes from Log[2, 2/3.*Pi^2*1/n^2] for the log of the average, and the adjustment factor, that becomes a summand on taking logs, accounting for the ratio of the means as indicated earlier.
How well does this track?
(* estimatedtablebig = Table[estimated[n], {n, 6000, 10000, 2000}];

Transpose[{entropytablebig, estimatedtablebig, 
  entropytablebig/estimatedtablebig}]

(* Out[117]= {{22.8956, 22.9805, 0.996306}, {23.7254, 23.8106, 
  0.99642}, {24.3689, 24.4545, 0.996501}} *) *)

So we have discrepancies around .35 percent.
I will note that the estimated by @azerbajdzan has errors only around half that. But they seem to be rising in the range where mine are falling.
A weak spot in this analysis has to do with the clustering shown in the response by @ydd. I do not have any good estimate there. I can get a small and asymptotically meaningless refinement of my estimate above, by accounting for the two terms of size 1/n (or 1/(n-1) if n is even). But this gives an adjustment of -log2(n)/n which, for n=10000, is -.00133. Are there "many" terms that are in some sense much larger that O(1/n^2)? It is not difficult to show that the total count of these must be o(n^2). But I still have no handle on how, or to what extent, they might change the constant part of the estimate. I do not have a proof that the log part is correct, although the heuristic arguments presented here and by @ydd indicate the plausibility.

I defined OP's entropy a bit differently as newentropy. It is a bit faster on my PC.
Precomputing fraction lists up to m=300 (it took 0.7 seconds):
$RecursionLimit = 2000;
Clear[fr]
m = 300;

fr[1] = {1/2};
fr[x_] := fr[x] = Union[fr[x - 1], Range[(x - 1)/2]/x]
fr[m]; // AbsoluteTiming


{0.727258, Null}

Definition of newentropy:
Clear[newentropy]
newentropy[1] = 0;
newentropy[n_] := 
 newentropy[n] = 
  N[Total[-2 # Log[
         2, #] & /@ ((Flatten@(Differences /@ 
            GatherBy[fr[n], EvenQ@*Denominator]))/((
         2 (n - 1)^2 - 1 + (-1)^n)/((n - 1) n)))] - (3 # Log[
         2, #] &@(((2 n - 1 + (-1)^n)/(
        2 (n - 1) n))/((2 (n - 1)^2 - 1 + (-1)^n)/((n - 1) n))))]

Verifying that my newentropy is identical to OP's entropy:
Table[newentropy[n] == entropy[n], {n, 1, 300}] // Union


{True}

Finding the fit in three parameters {a, b, c} (while OP used only two) and plotting fit with entropy in the same plot. The next plot is difference between the two.
Computing table tEntropy took 20.8 seconds.
tEntropy = Table[newentropy[n], {n, m}];
fit = Normal@
  NonlinearModelFit[tEntropy, {a + b Log[x + c]}, {a, b, c}, x]
tFit = Table[fit, {x, m}];
ListLinePlot[{tEntropy, tFit}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, ColorData[97, 3]], 
   Directive[Thick, Dashing[Large], ColorData[97, 4]]}]
ListPlot[tEntropy - tFit]


-2.02903 + 2.85731 Log[0.699937 + x]


With m = 1000; computing fr[m] took 29.9 seconds and computing tEntropy took 16.4 minutes.
This is the result with m = 1000;:
-2.07043 + 2.86581 Log[0.738438 + x]




You should probably write, "This is an extended comment".

@Arbuja ??? Why? It is an answer not a comment. Namely, an answer to your "Try to find a reasonable approximation for the entropy[k]".

Sorry, I thought the redisuals were slowly increasing after $x=600$. If so, this wouldn't be nice for an asymptotic expansion.

More specifically, I want a reasonable upperbound.

@Arbuja It is oscillating around x-axis. Somewhere above 1000 it will go down again. You want a "reasonable upper bound"? Upper bound is not same as approximation. I am answering the original question which asks for "a reasonable approximation for the entropy[k]" not an upper bound.

Understood. If you can show the relative error approaches zero, I will accept your answer.

I agree with @azerbajdzan.  The title and the question in the text are different.  If an approximation is desired, then stating how close you need to be and what range of values of $k$ are desired are essential to know whether that question is answered.

@JimB I specified that I want an asymptotic expansion, but it's too late now. Still, if anyone's willing to answer the question in title than I'll accept.

@Arbuja If the model of the fit is correct then the fit will coincide with asymptotic at infinity. The more data you provide for the computation the more precise it will be.  What is wrong with -2.07043 + 2.86581 Log[0.738438 + x]? If you want it more precise then provide it more data.

@azerbajdzan I guess if I truly want to make sure the model of the fit coincides with asymptotic, then I should ask at math stack exchange. Hopefully, I'm right.

@Arbuja By the way, entropy of what is computed? You compute it as entropy of U1 but what does U1 represent?

U1 converts the elements in P1 into a probability distribution (i.e., list of elements that add up to 1). P1 is the length of the pathway of line segments connecting points in T1[k_]:=T1[k]=Table[{S1[k][[r]],1},{r,1,Length[S1[k]]}] and T2[k_]:=T2[k_]=Table[{S2[k][[r]],0},{r,1,Length[S2[k]]}] from an inital point in either list, which maximizes the entropy of U1 on T1 and T2. Basically, I'm creating an "integral" which can define an average on a function defined on the rationals.
